# perturbation analysis in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For a given Series I want to change the value of each element around it's current value and then calculate an arbitrary function (here `std`) as shown in the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.Series(np.random.randn(10))
perturb = {}
for item in range(2,len(a)):
    serturb = {}
    for ep in np.arange(-1,1,0.1):
        temp = a.ix[0:item]
        temp.iloc[-1] += ep
        serturb[ep] = temp.std()
    perturb[item] = pd.Series(serturb)
perturb = pd.DataFrame(perturb).T
```

The above code will become too slow for a large amount of data. The above process, when applied on a `DataFrame` would return a `Panel`. Is there an efficient way of doing it, since a lot of the calculations are being repeated?